# Нужно ли удваивать букву? "Пазл" - "puzzle"

Tags: орфография, переводы

Слово "пазл" взято из английского "puzzle". Нужно ли в русском удваивать З, как это имеет место быть в оригинале?

Comment: Соглашусь, что правильное написание - загадка, мозаика или головоломка. "Пазл" всего лишь бездумный перенос с английского.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь - нет. Надо просто заглянуть в словарь. 
А вообще вопрос удвоенных согласных при переводе (вернее сказать - переносе) очень неоднозначен, очень трудно делать какие-то обобщения. Во-первых, зависит от языка-источника. Во-вторых, сильно влияние моды. Сейчас по моим наблюдениям стремятся следовать фонетическому принципу, если произносится в русском удвонная, её и пишут. Но ранее чаще во главу угла ставили написание в языке-источнике. Так что самое правильное - смотреть в словарь.

Answer (score 2):

Нет. не нужно. Пазл.

Answer (score -1):

Вопрос - поцелуй в фалду (Гашек) американца. 
Puzzle - загадка, мозаика, головоломка, складка, составитель, конструктор, задача...

Формула Дайхеса
Лёлик неуверенно знает русский и уверенно не знает английский.

Его Величество Русский Язык
Ея Величество Русская Культура